# black.list file does not contain all entries (pi-hole)

Tags: pihole

in my pi-hole there are around 50 manual entries in my blacklist shown on the webpage of the pi-hole. But when I do

> cat /etc/pihole/black.list

there are only the first 6 entries which are shown.
What would be the correct way to export or cat the blacklist on the console?

The out put of "ls /etc/pihole/" is

```
adlists.list.old                           list.4.s3.amazonaws.com.domains
black.list                                 localbranches
dhcp.leases                                local.list
dns-servers.conf                           localversions
GitHubVersions                             logrotate
gravity.db                                 macvendor.db
gravity.list                               migration_backup
install.log                                pihole-FTL.conf
list.0.raw.githubusercontent.com.domains   pihole-FTL.db
list.1.mirror1.malwaredomains.com.domains  pihole-FTL.db.backup
list.2.sysctl.org.domains                  setupVars.conf
list.3.s3.amazonaws.com.domains            setupVars.conf.update.bak
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:

```
$ pihole -g -f
```

Then check the file again to see if the problem is resolved.